# How to create a copy of the items in a domainupdown C#

Tags: c#, list, copy, items

I was able to copy decimal values from a `numericUpDown` box fine, but when I try to copy items from a `DomainUpDown` box with a predefined collection of items to a new `DomainUpDown` box I run into problems since I think it may be an array of strings. Here is what I have so far:

```
private DomainUpDown sentNUD2;

private void domainUpDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formPopUpData2 newForm = new formPopUpData2();
    this.sentNUD2 = (DomainUpDown)sender;
    DomainUpDown copiedNUD = new DomainUpDown();

    for (int i = 0; i <= this.sentNUD2.Items.Count-1; i++)
    {
        copiedNUD.Items[i] = this.sentNUD2.Items[i];
    }
```

My code above is similar to what I did with the numeric boxes, but the addition is the for loop for the array. I keep getting an out of bounds error. Is there an easier way to copy items from one `DomainUpDown` to another? Am I on the right track? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this code runs, copiedNUD.Items has count of zero.  You need to use an Add method on the collection:

```
copiedNUD.Items.Add(this.sentNUD2.Items[i]); //fixed naming
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am getting error though. I took a screen of it, but I blacked out the file names for privacy purposes. http://i188.photobucket.com/albums/z265/fac7orx/domainupdowncopyerror_zpsd3c48833.png

Comment: (deleted my snarky comment) Sorry for the typo!

Comment: Thanks, that worked so far. I edited your post to fix the typo I missed, doh! :D